# Automatically renaming a file after uploading it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, file-upload

I have a Music folder like you can see in the following image

[image: Music folder]

And the following code to upload the music

```
private IWebHostEnvironment _environment;
public UploadFileModel(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
{
    _environment = environment;
}

[BindProperty]
public IFormFile Upload { get; set; }
public async Task OnPostAsync()
{
    var file = Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot/music", Upload.FileName);
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await Upload.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Inside the cshtml

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" asp-for="Upload" accept=".mp3"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

What I want to do is automatically renaming every new mp3 file to `"Track{last_number + 1}.mp3"` and in case a file was missing in the chain to take its place.

Comment: OK. Note that you haven't included a question. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know how can I do it, and I wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: How do you want it to work? I mean, how do you intend to determine last_number? By files that exist? By some database value? What?

Comment: By checking the files inside the folder.

Comment: So you need to break down your problem into 4 parts: 1) Get a list of current files. 2) Parse the current filenames to get their numbers. 3) Take the highest number and increment its value by 1. 4) Generate the new filename. -- 1-3 is probably a single loop through a list of filenames, followed by 4.

Comment: Re the replace missing file requirement: you'll probably need to loop through each existing number in order to check for any gaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed @John steps and wrote following code. Thanks @John.

```
private IWebHostEnvironment _environment;
public UploadFileModel(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
{
    _environment = environment;
}

[BindProperty]
public IFormFile Upload { get; set; }
public async Task OnPostAsync()
{
    var musicFileName = "Track0.mp3";
    var musicDirectory = Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot/music");
    var musicDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(musicDirectory);
    var fileNumbers = musicDirectoryInfo.GetFiles()
        .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name))
        .Select(x => GetFileNumber(x.Name))
        .OrderBy(x => x)
        .ToList();
    if (fileNumbers.Count > 0)
    {
        var fileNumber = fileNumbers.Last() + 1;
        var missingNumber = GetMissingNumber(fileNumbers);
        if (missingNumber.HasValue)
        {
            fileNumber = missingNumber.Value;
        }

        musicFileName = $"Track{fileNumber}.mp3";
    }

    var file = Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot/music", musicFileName);
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await Upload.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
}


private int GetFileNumber(String musicName)
{
    var lastFileNumber = musicName.Replace("Track", "").Replace(".mp3", "");
    var fileNumber = Convert.ToInt32(lastFileNumber);
    return fileNumber;
}

private static int? GetMissingNumber(List<int> numbers)
{
    var missingNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, numbers.Last()).Except(numbers).ToList();
    if (missingNumbers.Count > 0)
        return missingNumbers.FirstOrDefault();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I wanted except that it doesn't replace a missing Track in case it was deleted.

Comment: Thank you sir, that's exactly what I was looking for.